# Proof of existence of a sequence with a property

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, induction

For a positive even integer $n$ prove that there is a sequence $a_0,a_1,\ldots a_{n-1}$ where each $a_i$ is unique and $1\leq a_i \leq n$ and $a_i+a_{i+1}$ is prime ($i$ is in $\pmod{n}$).

The only way I can think of to solve this problem is either to use induction on $n$, or the well-ordering principle.

Assume that there is no sequence such that that condition holds. Then by the well-ordering principle, there exists a smallest $i$ such that there doesn't exist an $a_{i+1}$ with $a_i+a_{i+1}$  prime. I have no idea how to continue in this case because you would need to show that there is a $j<i$ such that $a_{j}+a_{j+1}$ is not prime, but just from there is no real information that I can see that would tell us that. So onto the inductive argument which seems more promising.

For the inductive argument, it boils down to adding in $n+1$ and $n+2$ somewhere in the sequence so that it preserves the condition. But you would need to know something about which numbers are primes here I think. Are there any useful theorems I could use to show this? Are there any other directions I could tackle this from? A necessary condition for the sum of two numbers to be prime is that they are relatively prime, but this isnt sufficient.

Comment: What do you meanwith "$a_i$ is unique"? For $n=4$, we certainly have sequences $1,2,3,4$ as well as $4,3,2,1$ as well as $1,1,1,1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  i mean that every number from 1 to n is used exactly once.

Comment: Could you say where you got this problem/why you think this is true? Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewConroy I got it from a graduate course i took last semester. My professor stated it as a fact without any proof, since there was no proof provided i tried to google the problem or see if there were any papers on the subject but i couldn't find any. So i tried to prove it myself

Comment: Have you worked out any examples? I think there might be some clues you could get by doing that.

Comment: @MatthewConroy i wrote a program to find all such sequences. I guess i should group together related sequences. Maybe start with n=12 and then delete the highest two elements and see if the condition holds, and then only work with those. That might be a good way to see a pattern emerge.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Well I think trying to build up the sequences up inductively is a bust. First of all, given a sequence such that the above condition holds, if we can build a sequence from a smaller one, we can break up a bigger one into a smaller one. So if we delete $n$ and $n-1$ in any sequence where they are not adjacent, you necessarily get a sequence with composite adjacent sums.

Comment: This means $a_0,a_1,\ldots a_{n-1}$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,n$, right?

Comment: @ultrainstinct Yes, the terms have to alternate parity, so removing any nonadjacent pair of terms results in a permutation with non-prime sums.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Do you have any ideas on a means of attacking this problem? If sequences between varying $n$ aren't related, would you need to construct a specific sequence and show that the rule for building the sequence exhaustively lists numbers from $1$ to $n$? If we pick the rule correctly it could have the primality portion built in, and you would just need to prove that it lists all the numbers uniquely. Do you think this would be too difficult?

Comment: Assume the permuted sequence is $1,$ $2w,$ $1+2v,$ $2w-2v,$ $1+4w,$ $2w-4v,$ $\ldots$ and replace a number $t$ by $n-t$ if $t \le 0.$ The sum of two adjacent numbers is $1+2w,$ $1+2w+2v,$ $1+2w+n$ or $1+2w+2v+n.$ If these four numbers are prime and $\gcd(v,n/2)=1$ we have found an example for such a sequence. I think for most even $n$ it is simple to find such a sequence.

Comment: This OEIS sequence gives the number of such permutations, but unfortunately no links to proofs that this number is always positive.http://oeis.org/A103839

Comment: @MatthewConroy if $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ has the property then $a_n,\ldots,a_2,a_1$ has the property, too. So the number of such sequences is even. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597408/proof-of-existence-of-a-sequence-with-a-property#comment5364064_2597408) is a link to the proof.

Comment: @miracle73 I agree: the number of such sequences is even.  Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Sorry, I misread your comment as "no links to proofs that this number is always *even*". btw thus is not the correct sequence because it does not request tha $a_n+a_1$ is prime.

Comment: @MatthewConroy I think this is the right one http://oeis.org/A051252

Comment: http://oeis.org/A051252 says "There is no known proof that a(n) > 0 for all n."

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCircle.html

Comment: http://mathforum.org/wagon/current_solutions/s1218.html

Comment: @miracle173 Hmmm now I see why my professor put this in a combinatorial gray codes class. It is really similar to all the statements of other gray codes in that it is asking whether a certain graph is hamiltonian. I found this http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~csr52/Contact_files/Prime%20Sum%20Graphs%20-IITB%20Drexel%20Univ.pdf

Comment: @miracle173 The algorithm mentioned on the OEIS page seems very similar to an algorithm discovered by Martin in the 1930s that generates the lex smallest de Bruijn sequence. Basically add the largest digit to the sequence that you can so that new n-tuple created hasn't been seen before. Maybe his proof would be of value, but I doubt it since proving a rule induces a Hamiltonian cycle in the de Bruijn graph is pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a citation from [TheMathForum](http://mathforum.org/wagon/current_solutions/s1218.html)

> The problem is known as the "Prime Circle Problem" and is due to Antonio Filz (Problem 1046, J. Recr. Math. vol 14, p 64, 1982; vol 15, p 71, 1983). It appears in the classic book by Richard Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 2nd edition, §C1. See MathWorld's entry and The New York Times' Numberplay blog post on the puzzle.(...) Good information about the problem is available from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences entries for sequences A051252, A072616, and A227050, the last two of which describe even stronger versions that seem to be true.
>   (...)
>   Nothing is known about how to find a general proof for all n, but there are several interesting computational approaches.

So it seems to be an open problem.

Comment: Yes, some quick googling on the graph theoretic interpretation and I found that myself too. http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~csr52/Contact_files/Prime%20Sum%20Graphs%20-IITB%20Drexel%20Univ.pdf and https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/openp/primegraph.html